# Apache-Wicket renders tag <wicket:panel> in page body

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm working with the tutorial "Navomatic" from wicket page. I modified it, so it does not contain the "Border" tags. I want to do the "magic" with panels. But when I create the panel, wicket renders the tag  in the page body.

My LeftPanel.java:

```
public class LeftPanel extends Panel {
    public LeftPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

My markup to that class, LeftPanel.html:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <a href="#">Page A</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">Page B</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">Page C</a>
</wicket:panel>
```

Result is the following page:

[image]

I add the panel to body like:

```
add(new LeftPanel("navigationBorder"));
```

And in the markup:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="navigationBorder">
        Left div
    </div>
    <div wicket:id="bodyBorder">
        Right div
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wicket leaves the `<wicket>` elements in the generated source when in "development mode" to aid debugging.  Try using deployment mode by adding the following in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>configuration</param-name>
    <param-value>deployment</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you want to strip out the wicket elements even in development mode, you can call `getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(true)` in the `init` method of your Application class.

More information can be found on [the Wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+remove+wicket+markup+from+output).

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!